# With which FTP command can I find a specific file?

Tags: ftp

I want the FTP command to search for following:
1) Specific file name (for example - "abc.sql")
2) Specific content inside a file (inside .php/.js/.sql/.tpl files)
As there are many folders it will take some time to find that manually.

I am sure there is a command for 1, maybe also for 2, could someone please let me know what I need to enter to find that out. Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ftp protocol does not support either operation. You can read the definition of ftp here to see what is possible: 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/

An ftp client could implement the search operation by recursively listing directory contents, but to search for contents inside files it would have to download all files.

It's possible that some ftp servers include support for these operations through site specific commands.